# PayPal button as 'link' rather than 'form'

Tags: php, email, button, paypal, hyperlink

I currently have the following PayPal button with the values and 'item_name' and 'amount' being inserted dynamically via PHP.

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="info@example.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $title; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $amount; ?>">
<input type="image" src="http://www.example.com/paypal-button.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Click here to pay now">
</form>
```

Is there a way to have the same data set as a 'link' rather than a 'form'?

I am aware that you can set up PayPal buttons as links manually via their site, with fixed pricing etc, but I would like to set the price using PHP.

The purpose of this is so that the same code can be used as a link to be sent via email.

This may not be possible - any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can do it via some jquery, 
Add a link and hide the form button then via jquery submit the form when click on the link.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may work something like this.

```
<form class="clickformsubmit" name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
 <input type="hidden" name="business" value="info@example.com">
 <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
 <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $title; ?>">
 <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $amount; ?>">
 <input style="display:none;" type="image" src="http://www.example.com/paypal-button.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Click here to pay now">
</form>
<a href="javascript:;" class="click_here">Click to send to paypal</a>
```

then script for this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(function(){
   jQuery('.click_here').click(function(){
        jQuery('.clickformsubmit').submit();
   });
});
</script>
```

You must include jQuery in header or footer for this

**Note : ** you can use `$` sign instead of `jQuery`

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply, this works perfectly in browser.

I think I may be looking for too much when it comes to using this method for creating buttons within emails, may have to stick to using standard PayPal buttons.